# How can I create a fair vacation scheduling roster for my team?

Tags: probability, combinations

I have a team of five employees and must manage their vacation requests to ensure that I have adequate coverage. Days next to holidays are very popular (i.e., taking Friday, July 1st off to create a longer July 4th weekend).

I need 3 of the 5 people to be at work on these popular vacation days.

If there are seven opportunities for long weekends for the rest of the year, and if I have five employees (two of whom may be off at once), how many long weekend opportunities can each person have?

Comment: "fair" might not be answered by mathematics, since it depends on preference somewhat. Some long weekends may be considerably more attractive than others

Answer (score 1):

If your answer is just about how many is **possible**, then it is easy. Each such opportunity gives at most $2$ people a long weekend, so there are a total of at most $7 \times 2 = 14$ long weekends, which are distributed over $5$ people. Clearly you can guarantee each person at least $\lfloor \frac{14}{5} \rfloor = 2$ long weekends, and it is even possible to give everyone but one person $3$ long weekends, but the one who gets only $2$ long weekends might likely complain! Here is one of many possible schedules:

```
A: 1110100
B: 1011010
C: 1101011
D: 0101101
E: 0010111
```

Here `1` denotes presence and `0` denotes absence, and `C` is the one who gets only $2$ long weekends.

Comment: Clearly, this may not be a real-world solution because employees often want to have some **choice** in which long weekends they want to have! In that case it might be better to use some kind of bidding system.